# Overridden UIPickerView instantiated on simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uipickerview

In my project I have a subclass `A` of a `UIPickerView`.
In Interface Builder I have a `UIPickerView` whose type I have changed to my subclass `A`.
In another class `B`, also defined in my code, instantiated in Interface Builder and linked to `A` via its outlet, it refers to `A` with an IBOutlet field `A *mySubclass`.

**The problem is this:**
When running on the simulator it works fine; A breakpoint on `B`’s `awakeFromNib` confirms that `mySubclass` has been loaded and is indeed of type `A`.
When running on the device (iOS4.1 on iPhone 4) however, the same breakpoint reveals that `mySubclass` is now of type `UIPickerView`.

Adding an `awakeFromNib` to subclass `A` confirms that when running on the simulator `A`’s awakeFromNib gets called but not when running on the device.

Has anyone any idea why this might be?

Thanks in advance for any help,

Teo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update:

After a couple of days of trying everything I eventually started trying some example projects on the device (which worked) and finally created a new project with the intention of migrating the code across in case the project itself had somehow gotten broken.

Having named the new project the same as the problematic one I noticed I couldn’t run it because of an UDID mismatch.

This caused me to have a look at the apps on the device through the Xcode organizer and noticed I had two of the same app on there. Deleting those made everything work again. Sigh. Glad it's sorted but if anyone has any idea exactly what happened I'd love to hear it.

Thanks for the eyeballs and sorry for asking an impossible problem although anyone reading this might now try removing the offending app from their device sooner rather than later.

Best, Teo